# Понятие + им. падеж сущ. - это "сущ." в кавычках?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

> Впервые сталкиваемся мы вот так прямо – лицом к лицу – **с понятием
>   фреска**, мы увидим их много во Флоренции и важно остановиться на
>   технических тонкостях.

Чтобы не страдать об запятой перед *и важно*, м. б., разбить предложение?

*Впервые сталкиваемся мы вот так прямо – лицом к лицу – с понятием
"фреска". Мы увидим их много во Флоренции, и важно остановиться на
технических тонкостях.*

Ну как?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Впервые сталкиваемся мы вот так прямо – лицом к лицу – с понятием фресковой живописи ("фресковая живопись");  во Флоренции  много  фресок, и поэтому так важно остановиться на технических тонкостях.**

1) Повтор "мы".

2) Даже при согласовании в И.п. часто ставятся кавычки, если речь идет не о термине, а именно о понятии, а здесь еще и падежи разные.

Пример:

В связи с тем, что понятие «эффективность», как и понятие «информация», не имеет однозначного толкования ...[Интерпретации и смысл понятия «информация» // «Информационные технологии», 2004]

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EF%EE%ED%FF%F2%E8%E5

Comment: А еще здесь добавлено слово *поэтому* — и эта добавка помогает мысли плавно скользить, а не прыгать.

Comment: Но все-таки я думаю, что "фреска" и "их" — неверное согласование.

Comment: Понятие - это только приложение с слову фреска,  то есть определение, выраженное существительным, поэтому ясно, что речь идет о фресках.

Comment: А несогласованность в числе?

Comment: Понятие - одно,  а фресок  много.  А вы как предлагаете написать: мы сталкиваемся с понятием "фреска" , мы увидим много фресок. Повтор на повторе.

Comment: Но нарушение правил - не выход из положения. На несогласованность в числе прямо указывал Розенталь: "При употреблении местоимения 3-го лица нередко нарушается согласование (соотнесенность) в числе" (Справочник по русскому языку, Практическая стилистика, Розенталь Д.Э., 2001, Глава 10)

Answer (score 1):

Да, второй вариант лучше. Пунктуация больше соответствует логике текста.

Comment: А чё так лаконично-то? У мя один вариант - мой! А цитата не в счёт!

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поставил точку с запятой. Точка на втором месте. Запятая на третьем.

> ...с понятием "фреска". Мы увидим их...

Речь о фресках, а не о понятиях, и число не согласуется (*фреска*, но *их*), посему я бы написал: "**Мы увидим фрески...**"

На несогласованность в числе как на ошибку прямо указывал Розенталь:[image: 1]]

(Справочник по русскому языку, Практическая стилистика, Розенталь Д.Э., 2001, Глава 10)

Comment: У художников так: что фреска, что скульптура. ("Летний сад украшен скульптурой".)